# Let $c$ be any common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Use induction to show that $c$ must divide $r_j$ for all $j$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is in reference to the Euclidean Algorithm, namely

\begin{align*}
        a = q_1b + r_1
        \\
        b = q_2r_1 + r_2
        \\
        r_1 = q_3r_2 + r_3
        \\
        .
        \\
        .
        \\
        .
        \\
        r_{k-2} = q_k r_{k-1} + r_k
        \\
        r_{k-1} = q_{k+1}r_k
\end{align*}

I am really not sure how to set up the induction for this at all. I can't seem to have a general expression that I can extrapolate to be $P(j) \implies P(j+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case $j = 1$:

Let $a = cn$, $b = cm$. Now

\begin{align}
a &= q_1b + r_1 \\
r_1 &=  a-q_1b \\
r_1 &=  c(n-q_1m).
\end{align}
Hence $c$ divides $r_1$.

Assume that $c$ divides $r_j$ for all $1 \leq j \leq k$ and write $r_{k-1} = cn'$, $r_{k} = cm'$. Now
\begin{align}
r_{k-1} &= q_{k+1}r_{k} + r_{k+1} \\
r_{k+1} &= r_{k-1} - q_{k+1}r_{k}  \\
r_{k+1} &= c( n'-q_{k+1}m'). 
\end{align}
Hence $c$ divides $r_{k+1}$.